# NameError: global name 'linregress' is not defined

Tags: python, scipy, jupyter, linear-regression, nameerror

I have a function that creates scatter plot and calculte the fit and the R aquare.  I have run this two hours ago no problem but now I have tried to run it and I have gotten new error:

> NameError: global name 'linregress' is not defined

The problematic part is from the scipy library and I can't find any mistake in the letters:

```
import seaborn as sns
from scipy import stats

def give_me_scatter(x, y, title, xlabel, ylabel):
#The problematic line:
    slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = linregress(x, y)
    #print('slope:',slope)
    #print('intercept:',intercept)
    #print('R:',r_value)
    #print('R^2:',(r_value**2))  

    # use line_kws to set line label for legend
    plt.figure(figsize=(7.5,6.5))
    ax = sns.regplot(x='NDVI', y='nitrogen', data=merged_data, color='b', line_kws={'label':"y={0:.1f}x+{1:.1f}".format(slope,intercept)})
    ax = sns.regplot(x='NDVI', y='nitrogen', data=merged_data,color='b', line_kws={'label':"R^2={0:.3}".format(r_value**2)})
    ax.set_title('NDVI vs Nitrogen% ')

    # plot legend
    ax.legend()
    plt.show()

    # plot legend

    ax.legend()
    plt.show()

#The error appears when I try to show the chart:

give_me_scatter(x, y, 'NDVI vs Nitrogen ', 'NDVI', 'Nitrogen %')
```

I have restart the kernel few times but still getting error in this stage.

Comment: Can you show your import statements?

Comment: @Chris Doyle what do you mean by import statment? sorry i'm new to data science

Comment: well you are trying to use `linregress` from the `scipy.stats` module. So to use that you would have to first import the module. like `from scipy.stats import linregress`. So can you show your import statement?

Comment: Great, i have added the import as an answer for completeness to your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you wish to use `linregress` function from the `scipy.stats` module then you will need to first import it so your script knows about it. you can define the below import statement at the top of your scripts.

`from scipy.stats import linregress`

Answer (score 1):

are you sure you did not forget to import library?
For example,

```
from scipy import stats
def give_me_scatter(x, y, title, xlabel, ylabel):
#The problematic line:
    slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x, y)
```

Comment: sorry I forgot to put it in my post, I have added it now. Yes, I have import this.

Comment: Try stats.linregress(x, y) instead of linregress(x, y)